# ChromeProxyService - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

When I run my app using Chrome, this error appears.
This is the code:
`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

`

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Y8Y.png)
[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7FM.png)

I have tried to upgrade flutter, but it didn´t worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, please [edit] your question title to be more clear about the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is a single word plus the information already in the tags. You can find more information about writing a good title by reading [ask]. Youi can find it in the [help], and reading the help pages to learn how the site works before posting will greatly improve your experiences here in the future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.